# How to install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I installed **virtualenv** and **virtualenvwrapper** using :

```
$ pip install virtualenv
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

I tried this command to create a virtual environment:

```
$ mkvirtualenv myproject
```

but it gives me this error:

**'mkvirtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

**OS**: *Windows 10*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenvwrapper%5D+mkvirtualenv+is+not+recognized

Comment: `pip install virtualenvwrapper-win`

Comment: thank you so much!:)